# Certificates issue with a perl script

Tags: perl, ssl-certificate, lwp-useragent

I need to use an url to connect with **OSTR** to create a ticket via **webservice**, but I have a problem with **certificates**.

The error ([picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2SiG.png)):

```
500 Can't connect to         (certificate verify failed)
```

---

### What I've tried

- `$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;`
- `my $UA = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0, } );`
- I've also tried to add a new certificate in `C:\otrs\Kernel\cpan-lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem.`

---

### CODE

Code [(Picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1grfF.png)

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: Of course, I let you the code in the linked picture

Comment: That's not the code, that's just part of the error message.

Comment: I was referring to the other picture, the one below the "What I've tried" part

Answer (score 0):

Well, please try this code and add/remove the line which sets the env variable, for me this *just works*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use SOAP::Lite;

$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME} = 0;
my $URL = 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/foo';
my $NameSpace = 'https://self-signed.badssl.com/';
my $Operation = 'TicketCreate';

my $XMLData = <<'XML';
<UserLogin>login</UserLogin>
<Password>pass</Password>
<Ticket>
  <Title>Title</Title>
</Ticket>
XML

my $SOAPObject = SOAP::Lite->uri($NameSpace)->proxy($URL)->$Operation($XMLData);
```

Without the `$ENV{}` line it gives `500 Can't connect ... (certificate verify failed)` and with it it gives `405 Not Allowed` (since the test URL does not actually run the SOAP web service).

Also, please place actual code snippets on SO, in text and not in a screenshot, and please try and keep them short.

Oh, and by the way, I wrote a small script to create tickets in OTRS using the web service, it's here, maybe it's useful for you -> https://github.com/mbeijen/App-OTRS-CreateTicket